# 404 error with .htaccess url slug without a hyphen

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to .htaccess and I've been working on a site where I have used URL slugs. Everything is working perfectly fine with slugs that have hyphens in them, but I get 404 error when I have a one word slug.

`https://www.example.com/blog/example-blog` works fine but `https://www.example.com/blog/example` throws a 404 error.

Below is the `.htaccess` code I'm currently using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/season\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?url=$1&season=$2 [NC]
  
</IfModule>
```

I've searched everywhere on Search Engine but got no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

**Summary:**

I'm looking for ways for `.htaccess` to accept a slug without a hyphen as those with hyphens are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
> ```

This rule will catch the request `/example` and unconditionally rewrites it to `example.php`. Whereas `/example-blog` (with a hyphen) is ignored by this rule (because the regex `^([a-z]+)\/?$` does not match).

If this rule is required then add an additional condition that checks for the existence of the `.php` file before rewriting (otherwise this rule should be removed altogether). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, only requests that actually map to `.php` files are rewritten.

**UPDATE:**

I've added the `L` flag to the above rule, although it will still work without.

So, in summary, your complete set of rules should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/season/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&season=$2 [L]
```

There's no need to backslash-escape slashes in the regex, so I've removed the unnecessary backslashes. The `NC` flag is superfluous on the last two rules since you are already matching `a-zA-Z` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. And I've added the `L` flag, since you want processing to stop after the rewrite.

The `<IfModule>` container is also not required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though mine isn't re-writing to a file, I'm simply creating sort of a directory. And the code you provided will not work for numbers if I'm right, the slug url could contain alpha-numeric characters

Comment: @ObedgiuDerrick "though mine isn't re-writing to a file" - exactly, but that's what that directive would do (in error), without the preceding _condition_. "the code you provided will not work for numbers" - I did not provide any new rule or changed anything with regards to numbers, I simply added a _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) to your 1st rule. "the slug url could contain alpha-numeric characters" - which is presumably handled by the last two rules.

Comment: @ObedgiuDerrick That first rule (without the condition) would explain the difference in behaviour between `/example-blog` and `/example`, as I've stated in my answer. Since that rule would only target `/example`, rewriting it to `/example.php` which is presumably what's resulting in the 404. I've updated my answer with a complete summary of what your directives should look like. Of course, if you don't need that first rule, then it should be removed altogether.